# Ubuntu 20.04 - No sound

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, 20.04

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I noticed that I have no sound, I am using Lenovo Legion Y520-15IKBN. I want to continue using Ubuntu and learning about Linux, but having no sound is a kind of a deal breaker for me and going back to Windows is my last resort.

I have tried every Google result, and every "solution" but nothing is working. I also apologize if a thread like this already exists, but I was really digging around ask Ubuntu and I couldn't find any solutions.

Thank you for your help, and sorry for my English :)

First I want to say that when I plug in my USB headphones, audio is working just fine, the problem is with laptop's built in speakers and microphone.

Here is what I know:

1. `sudo lspci` outputs:

   ```
   00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
   00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
   00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
   00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
   00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
   00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
   00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
   00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
   00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
   00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
   00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM175 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
   00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
   00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
   00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
   01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
   02:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
   03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
   04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
   05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
   ```
2. `sudo lspci -v` outputs:

   ```
   00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
       Subsystem: Lenovo Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
       Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>
       Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

   00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
       Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
       I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff [size=4K]
       Memory behind bridge: a3000000-a3ffffff [size=16M]
       Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090000000-00000000a1ffffff [size=288M]
       Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: Lenovo Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
       Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
       Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
       Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
       Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
       Capabilities: [140] Root Complex Link
       Capabilities: [d94] Secondary PCI Express
       Kernel driver in use: pcieport

   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
       Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 630
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 138
       Memory at a2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
       Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
       I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
       Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
       Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
       Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
       Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
       Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
       Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
       Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
       Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
       Kernel driver in use: i915
       Kernel modules: i915

   00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
       Subsystem: Lenovo 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
       Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
       Memory at a4410000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
       Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
       Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
       Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

   00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
       Subsystem: Lenovo 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
       Memory at a442a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
       Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
       Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
       Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
       Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

   00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
       Subsystem: Lenovo 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 136
       Memory at a442b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
       Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
       Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
       Kernel driver in use: mei_me
       Kernel modules: mei_me

   00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
       Subsystem: Lenovo HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
       Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128
       Memory at a4428000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
       Memory at a442e000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
       I/O ports at 5080 [size=8]
       I/O ports at 5088 [size=4]
       I/O ports at 5060 [size=32]
       Memory at a442c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
       Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
       Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
       Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
       Kernel driver in use: ahci
       Kernel modules: ahci

   00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
       Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
       I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
       Memory behind bridge: a4300000-a43fffff [size=1M]
       Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
       Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
       Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
       Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port
       Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
       Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
       Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
       Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
       Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
       Kernel driver in use: pcieport

   00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
       Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
       I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
       Memory behind bridge: a4200000-a42fffff [size=1M]
       Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
       Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
       Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
       Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port
       Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
       Capabilities: [100] Null
       Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
       Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
       Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
       Kernel driver in use: pcieport

   00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
       Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
       I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff [size=4K]
       Memory behind bridge: a4100000-a41fffff [size=1M]
       Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
       Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
       Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
       Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port
       Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
       Capabilities: [100] Null
       Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
       Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
       Kernel driver in use: pcieport

   00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
       Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
       I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
       Memory behind bridge: a4000000-a40fffff [size=1M]
       Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
       Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
       Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
       Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port
       Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
       Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
       Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
       Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
       Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
       Kernel driver in use: pcieport

   00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM175 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
       Subsystem: Lenovo HM175 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
       Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

   00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
       Subsystem: Lenovo 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
       Memory at a4424000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

   00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
       Subsystem: Lenovo CM238 HD Audio Controller
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
       Memory at a4420000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
       Memory at a4400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
       Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
       Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
       Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
       Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

   00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
       Subsystem: Lenovo 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus
       Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
       Memory at a442d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
       I/O ports at 5040 [size=32]
       Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
       Kernel modules: i2c_i801

   01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
       Subsystem: Lenovo GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
       Memory at a3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
       Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
       Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
       I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
       Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
       Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
       Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
       Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
       Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
       Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
       Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
       Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
       Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
       Capabilities: [900] Secondary PCI Express
       Kernel driver in use: nvidia
       Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

   02:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 01)
       Subsystem: Lenovo SD/MMC Card Reader Controller
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
       Memory at a4301000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
       Memory at a4300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
       Capabilities: [6c] Power Management version 3
       Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
       Capabilities: [80] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
       Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
       Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
       Capabilities: [230] Latency Tolerance Reporting
       Capabilities: [240] L1 PM Substates
       Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
       Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

   03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
       Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 137
       Memory at a4200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
       Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
       Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
       Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
       Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
       Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-28-f8-ff-ff-c0-f7-83
       Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
       Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
       Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
       Kernel modules: iwlwifi

   04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
       Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
       I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
       Memory at a4104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
       Memory at a4100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
       Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
       Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
       Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
       Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
       Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
       Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
       Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
       Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
       Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
       Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
       Kernel driver in use: r8169
       Kernel modules: r8169

   05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961 (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
       Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
       Memory at a4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
       Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
       Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
       Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
       Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=33 Masked-
       Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
       Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
       Capabilities: [158] Power Budgeting <?>
       Capabilities: [168] Secondary PCI Express
       Capabilities: [188] Latency Tolerance Reporting
       Capabilities: [190] L1 PM Substates
       Kernel driver in use: nvme
       Kernel modules: nvme
   ```

I tried to purge pulse, alsa, reinstall them, but nothing seems to help.

When I type `alsamixer`, I get this:

```
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

[Here is the link of `alsa-info` script that I run on my laptop.](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=4437d9628954fce782c83be892af8450d02f82b3)

`dmsg` output is this:

```
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x200f0000
[    7.699475] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x200f0000
[    8.703470] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Codec #2 probe error; disabling it...
[    8.708107] hdaudio hdaudioC0D0: cannot read sub nodes for FG 0x10
[    8.708111] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: no codecs initialized
```

`sudo lshw -C multimedia`:

```
*-usb:0                   
       description: Video
       product: EasyCamera
       vendor: Chicony Electronics Co.,Ltd.
       physical id: 6
       bus info: usb@1:6
       version: 87.40
       serial: 0001
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: CM238 HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 31
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: irq:16 memory:a4420000-a4423fff memory:a4400000-a440ffff
```

`uname-a`:

```
Linux tomo-laptop 5.4.0-29-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 29 14:32:27 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I'm not sure how you got to the point you are at, but `alsamixer` is installed by default in 20.04 If you are missing it you can find it in the [alsa-utils package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=alsamixer)

Comment: i've got same as you, `CM238 rev 31` on a thinkpad t470. clean install of 20.04. showing in alsamixer but no sound actually appearing out of my machine

Comment: @ElderGeek It is a clean Ubuntu 20.04 install. I checked sums before installing, and they were ok, so the image is fine. I installed alsa-utils package but with no luck, still dummy output. I don't know if this is relevant but before I decided to run Ubuntu solo on my laptop I installed it in Wind Virtualbox, and everything was working. I assume that VBox is using Win drivers??

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] the output of `sudo lshw -C multimedia` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek edited ```  sudo lshw -C multimedia ``` into post. Hope we find some solution.

Comment: @WKPro Hopefully my [latest answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235880/225694) will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem. After installing Ubuntu 20.04 alongside my windows, I realized it has no sound. Reinstalling alsa-base and pulseaudio resolved it...

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

[Source](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/)

Comment: I run into this intermittently on 21.04 and `sudo also force-reload` appears to resolve the issue and restore sound.

Comment: @paul I seem to be in the same situation!

Comment: +1 and I would give you +10 if I could. I've been without sound in my DELL laptop for almost two years (since Ubuntu 20.04 was released). I just coped with it because I can use my smartphone, my tower PC, or my wife's Windows laptop to see videos. Anyway, it was really disappointing. I had tried at the beginning a few times and given up, I began even to wonder whether waiting for a jammy jellyfish could be the solution... (really?). But you made it with these two simple commands: Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I've had luck with `pavucontrol`. For some reason, the output selector from the Settings->Sound dialog box didn't work for me, but with `pavucontrol`, I was able to select the correct output.

```
$ sudo apt install pavucontrol
$ pavucontrol &
```

[image]

[image]

Port: **Headphones (unplugged)** works however system recognizes it as *unplugged*.

Comment: Tnx for your comment, but no luck for me with pavucontrol. I think that was the first thing I tried, but i only get dummy output :/

Comment: thats whats worked for me too (KDE Neon, sound stopped working after upgrade to 20.04)

Comment: +1 for `pavucontrol`. and thanks! When i type `lspci -v | grep Audio`, I've got two audio devices devices, one is related to NVidia HDMI. `pavucontrol` configuration displayed nvidia audio device  via HDMI was also turned, whereas I use Line-Out. After turning this off my audio has been working again.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with @user13595. I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and the sound problem persisted (both before and after). I have tried almost every possible solutions (reinstall `alsa` and `pulseaudio`, temporary fix for the kernel regression, etc) and none of them worked for me.

What I had to do was:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and add

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

to the end of the file.

Then `reboot` my machine.

#### Note:

Without tweaking this line, I only have `Dummy output`. After this tweak, I can see my NVIDIA HDMI output. If I want to make on-board Intel sound available, I have to **plug in my speaker first** and then **boot the machine**. Only then can I see both outputs (HDMI and onboard Intel one). What is more, the onboard Intel output will disappear, if I were to unplug my speaker and replug it, while my machine is running. In that case, I will have to keep the speaker plugged and reboot to make it work. Or I will have to avoid unplugging my speaker when my machine is on.

#### Source

> If you continue to get no sound output and still only see the Dummy Output in System Settings, you can try to set the model to `auto` instead of `generic`, so edit the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file with a text editor (as root) and change that. -- [click here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html)

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 4):

**If you have the "sound card not detected (dummy output)" problem:**
There's a regression in the 5.3.0-41 and -42 kernel that causes a new "dummy output" issue on Ubuntu 18.04 - 20.04 as explained in [this bug report.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1864061)

You can check your kernel version by issuing the command `uname -a`

In order to resolve this problem with the aforementioned kernels we need to do a few simple things.

Sources:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1864061

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html
***1)*** Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` as root and add `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` at the end of this file.

**If** you don't want to edit it manually you can achieve the same result by issuing the following command (**ONCE only**) `echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

***2)***  Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` as root and add blacklist snd_soc_skl at the end of the file.

**If** you don't want to edit it manually you can achieve the same result by issuing the following command **(ONCE only)** `echo "blacklist snd_soc_skl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

**3)** Reboot your system to make these changes take effect

Note: The developers are working on fixing this problem. **It may be necessary to revert these changes by removing the added lines in the aforementioned files after a kernel update** beyond the kernel versions mentioned.

Comment: This is the first thing I tried when I installed Ubuntu. No luck. I run Ubuntu as my only OS on my laptop, VM was only for testing while I was on Windows. By now I have tried numerous tutorials but nothing works :/ HDMI output has no sound, audio jack a well. Only BT and USB sound works.

Comment: @WKPro I thought the virst thing you tried was pavucontrol (or is this [comment incorrect?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231524/ubuntu-20-04-no-sound/1235880?noredirect=1#comment2074247_1232107) )please [edit] the output of `uname -a` into your post along with where you obtained your alsa information script. The latest is SCRIPT_VERSION=0.4.65 Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: your second link was the first thing I tried. I wrote that I think pavu control was the first thing I tried, but i was wrong :D. I edited ```unam -a``` in to th post. The script I used was SCRIPT_VERSION=0.4.65.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are running under virtualbox:** I freshly loaded 20.04 into a VM under virtualbox. To my surprise I found that the volume defaulted to mute (0%). I resolved this with the simple process of opening settings -> sound and boosting the volume at "Volume Levels" (System Sounds) (Default setting shown below)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me only worked to downgrade the kernel to 5.4.0-39 then reinstall pulseaudio and alsa-base as mentioned in a previous answer:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.4.0-39-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-39-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-39-generic 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Somewhere I read that the timidity-daemon can cause this too and it was the case for me, so I removed it:

```
sudo apt purge timidity-daemon
```

Then rebooted using the above kernel.

Note also that changing the `alsa-base.conf` and `blacklist.conf` files in `/etc/modprobe.d/` did not fix the issue for me. The "Dummy output" device changed to a real sound device but the sound still did not work. Therefore I commented the added lines at the end of these fies.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem: Upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, and sound disappeared. `pavucontrol` only showed HDMI sound under outputs, not my on-board Intel HDA sound.

I first tried the edits Elder Geek suggested above. They made no difference, so I reverted the changes by putting #'s in front of them.

Then I tried purging and reinstalling `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio`. It made no difference.

Then I ran `alsamixer` in a terminal, and lo and behold, my on-board sound showed up! By pressing F6 I could select it as output.

It still didn't show up in `pavucontrol`, so I ran `sudo alsa force-reload`, and now everything worked. `pavucontrol` even automatically selected my on-board sound.

I got the tips from this page: https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu/

Comment: I need to do `sudo alsa force-reload` every time I start Ubuntu, so it's not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately after many tries and tutorials I wasn't able to fix my sound problem. I bought BT speakers and I'm using them instead of my laptop speakers but I will not give up on trying to fix this. thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The following method worked for me:

1. Open a terminal (<Ctrl>+<Alt>+T)
2. Enter the command: `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
3. Add the following line at the end of alsa-base.conf: options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
4. Save alsa-base.conf
5. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar problem, followed many instructions but just a silly BIOS tweak did the charm:

```
go to BIOS -> disable Internal Speakers -> apply changes -> Enable again -> Apply changes -> Exit.
```

dell 3410

Answer (score 0):

I tried many of the solutions here including pavucontrol. I run Ubuntu on Lenovo T530. Finally this solution worked for me: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2442561

Answer (score 0):

Installing Wireplumer worked for me:

> sudo apt install wireplumber

Optional start and add it to system start:

> systemctl --user start wireplumber

> systemctl --user enable wireplumber

Answer (score -1):

From the Applications Menu choose Startup Applications; in the Name box write " Volume Control " : In the Command box type " pulseaudio --start " (that is pulseaudio, space,hyphen,hyphen start (ignore red underline)) and in Content box put something like Turn Sound on. Why that is not the default position I do not know.