# Sound not working with internal speakers on Legion 7 15IMHg05

Tags: sound, lenovo, alsa, realtek, speakers

Internal speakers are not working. Plugging in an external speaker in the jack works. I also have windows and there it works fine.

Tried most answers from here: [Ubuntu 20.04 - No sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231524/ubuntu-20-04-no-sound?newreg=fbc0ef15d53a4fd8ba16b2149b56d1e8)

System: Linux archy-Lenovo-Legion-7-15IMHg05 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Device info:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b44 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 380b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: b4000000-b60fffff [size=33M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000a0000000-00000000b20fffff [size=289M]
    Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [140] Root Complex Link
    Capabilities: [d94] Secondary PCI Express
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3fd1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 185
    Memory at b3000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b2690000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at b26a2000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [f0] PCI Advanced Features

00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3838
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b26a3000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3834
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
    Memory at b2680000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3835
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at b26a0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at b26a4000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3

00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0074
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b2698000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [164] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0010 Rev=0 Len=014 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3830
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 89c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3831
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at 89c01000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 382a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 168
    Memory at b26a7000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [a4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=3f, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00006000-00007fff [size=8K]
    Memory behind bridge: b2400000-b25fffff [size=2M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000089800000-0000000089bfffff [size=4M]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #17
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Null
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=40, subordinate=40, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: b2300000-b23fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b5 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=41, subordinate=41, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: b2200000-b22fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 06b5
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake LPC Controller
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3801
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3826
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 186
    Memory at b269c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b2100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3804
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at b26a8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3805
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at fe010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f55 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3fd1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 187
    Memory at b5000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at b4000000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [bb0] Resizable BAR <?>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo TU106 High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at b6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 130
    Memory at b2000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Memory at b2040000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo TU106 USB Type-C UCSI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 132
    Memory at b6004000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia-gpu
    Kernel modules: i2c_nvidia_gpu

06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Physical Slot: 16
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=06, secondary=07, subordinate=3f, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00006000-00006fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: b2400000-b25fffff [size=2M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000089800000-0000000089afffff [size=3M]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Lenovo JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Upstream Port, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [50] Capability ID 0x15 [0000]
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 1c-b6-38-00-43-b3-02-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=100 <?>
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=8086 Rev=2 Len=04c <?>
    Capabilities: [700] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [800] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [a00] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [b00] Precision Time Measurement
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

07:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Bus: primary=07, secondary=08, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: b2500000-b25fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Lenovo JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Downstream Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [50] Capability ID 0x15 [0000]
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 1c-b6-38-00-43-b3-02-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=100 <?>
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=8086 Rev=2 Len=04c <?>
    Capabilities: [700] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [900] Access Control Services
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

07:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Bus: primary=07, secondary=09, subordinate=3e, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00006000-00006fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000089800000-00000000899fffff [size=2M]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Lenovo JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Downstream Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [50] Capability ID 0x15 [0000]
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 1c-b6-38-00-43-b3-02-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=100 <?>
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=8086 Rev=2 Len=04c <?>
    Capabilities: [700] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [900] Access Control Services
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

07:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128
    Bus: primary=07, secondary=3f, subordinate=3f, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: b2400000-b24fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Lenovo JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Downstream Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [50] Capability ID 0x15 [0000]
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 1c-b6-38-00-43-b3-02-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=100 <?>
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=8086 Rev=2 Len=04c <?>
    Capabilities: [700] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [900] Access Control Services
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

08:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b2500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Memory at b2540000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 1c-b6-38-00-43-b3-02-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=100 <?>
    Capabilities: [600] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt
    Kernel modules: thunderbolt

3f:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 131
    Memory at b2400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 1c-b6-38-00-43-b3-02-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=100 <?>
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=8086 Rev=2 Len=04c <?>
    Capabilities: [700] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [800] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

40:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
    Memory at b2300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=33 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [158] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [168] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [188] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [190] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme

41:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at b2204000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at b2200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

```
  *-multimedia              
       description: Audio device
       product: TU106 High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:b6000000-b6003fff
  *-usb:0
       description: Audio device
       product: Avantree CF3001
       vendor: FongLun
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1
       version: 1.00
       serial: 201605
       capabilities: usb-1.10 audio-control
       configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
  *-usb:4
       description: Video
       product: Integrated Camera
       vendor: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 6
       bus info: usb@1:6
       version: 0.22
       capabilities: usb-2.01
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Comet Lake PCH cAVS
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: irq:186 memory:b269c000-b269ffff memory:b2100000-b21fffff
```

Full alsa-info: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=cb1223dcccf369296e5b2bd71db610e497bd7232

Comment: Did you find a solution?