# Ubuntu sound settings is disabled, not able to reset

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

Recently my headphone was not working with ubuntu, so search something in stackoverflow and fixed after sometime suddenly sound is not audible outside and mic is also not working. It's weird how it happened. Attached image for reference [image].

When i click Test in Output section, it coming below. Not sure what do to now. I had tried everything possible, some suggestion is appreciated

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. What are your headphones, machine and OS version?

Comment: Headphone - JBL wire headphone, Machine - Intel® Core™ i5-1035G1 CPU, OS - Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Comment: JBL has USB type or phone connector type headphones. i5-1035G1 laptops are a hundred different models. This information didn't help us provide an answer. However, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231524/ubuntu-20-04-no-sound) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul?noredirect=1&lq=1) is already a similar question. Would you explain how different your case is?

Answer (score 0):

Check the available audio cards,

```
pacmd list-cards
```

Look through the default.pa configuration file and search for an active profile.

active profile: output:analog-stereo

Also make a note of the index number, in case 1 or 0

```
sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

#Make some devices default
#set-default-sink output
#set-default-source input

Add the following under this:

```
set-card-profile 1 output:analog-stereo
```

Save the file in nano by Pressing CTRL + o and hitting enter

Then `CTRL + x` to exit nano

sudo shutdown -r now

**###OR**

check pavucontrol is active on your profile. Then uninstall pavucontrol and restart. Default configuration will be utilised.

Comment: Hi, i tried the above still it's not working. I haven't installed Pavucontrol.

Comment: check your available card through command "pacmd list-cards"

Then type the pavucontrol in terminal. Volume control --> output device --> Build-in audio analog stereo --> change your available card.

Comment: Hi @vijaykannan. pavucontrol is not loading for me. It's showing establishing connection to pulseaudio. Is there any way is there. Sorry for the delayed response.